# Uploading folder content to FTP with VBScript gives dialog box to overwrite existing file

Tags: vbscript, ftp, qlikview

This is one of the first times I am using VBScript to create a task I want to run in a program called Qlikview.

What I want to do is upload all the content of one local folder to an FTP folder but when a file is already on that FTP folder it just needs to "Overwrite All" so do "Yes to All" automatically

Here is my code:

```
Function FTPUpload(FTPHost, FTPUser, FTPPass, FTPPath)

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

On Error Resume Next

'Copy Options: 16 = Yes to All
Const copyType = 16

strFTP = "ftp://" & FTPUser & ":" & FTPPass & "@" & FTPHost

Set objFTP = oShell.NameSpace(strFTP)

'Upload all files in folder
If objFSO.FolderExists(FTPPath) Then
    'Code below can be used to upload entire folder
    Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(FTPPath)
    Wscript.Echo "Uploading folder " & FTPPath & " to " & strFTP
    objFTP.CopyHere objFolder.Items, copyType

End If

'If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'   Wscript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Description
'End If

On Error Goto 0

End function
```

I use `objFTP.CopyHere objFolder.Items, copyType` to copy the content and `copyType = 16` I found this on the internet [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx) where 16 stands for "Yes to All" when a dialog appears.

The problem is when I run this code, it uploads to the FTP but when a file exists I keep getting the overwrite dialog. What could be the problem?

Comment: I suspect the copyType=16 dialog suppression is honored only for a given folder; as other folders are traversed, it is invoked again.

Comment: I also spotted an article that indicates the copyType value to suppress *all* dialogs is actually 1556. Might give that a try.

Comment: Hmm not a solution but good info thx! My localfolder called "new" contains other folders "csv, excel, dayplanning" and in those folders contains the files. I just want to upload everything in one time without any dialog box when files already exist on the ftp server

Comment: Gotcha @Peter - that's why I was wondering if setting copyType=1556 might overcome the unwanted dialog issue. I think it's just the logical combination of all the suppression options.

Comment: Perhaps i need to use something like &H10& found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176633.aspx. Still not working but I have a feeling we're getting closer

Comment: That's just the VB/VBScript way of expressing the decimal value 16 in hex; it really shouldn't make any difference...the value is still the same. I take it that 1556 didn't work?

Comment: No it didn't it was good info but still no luck. I just removed all subfolders and made one file but it still asks me to overwrite even that one file without subfolders

Comment: it appears that perhaps you're just encountering one of those situations where the flags parameter just isn't honored. That's one of those "quiet caveats" in the docs and there's no way around it, unfortunately. That's frustrating.